# Publishing WebServices and IIS

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, iis, windows-xp

I'm having problems when publishing services on IIS.
First, I will describe my scenario.

At the moment I have an WPF app in C#.

Also I have a web site (published in IIS through HTTPS) that need to communicate with the c# application, therefore I decide to publish the methods I needed through a REST web service also through https:

```
WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(QESWebService), new Uri("https:xxx/WS/");
```

When I tested it on Windows 7 there were no problem. Everything works fine.

But now, when I try the application in Windows XP, it is not working! I cannot launch the application because the port 443(for the web service https) is already in use.

I cannot find a solution different to dont use https on one of the sides, but I really need it, What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have another web application/service using SSL under IIS ?

Comment: I have the web site configured to provide access through IIS, but there are not more services

Comment: check out this article to run multiple websites using SSL in IIS http://www.harbar.net/articles/ssl.aspx

Comment: yes, is configured with the certificated and can be accessed through HTTPS

Comment: check out the article, http://www.harbar.net/articles/ssl.aspx you need to do some configuration changes

Comment: But, why does it works on Windows 7 and not on XP?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10086/discussion-between-habib-osu-and-mario-a-corchero-jimenez)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a web application/service running on the IIS using SSL then you need to change some configuration settings
Here is an article about [Multiple SSL Web Applications on Port 443](http://www.harbar.net/articles/ssl.aspx)